# Ground Fault Protection In Consumer Electronics

Tags: ground, fault, consumer

Medical devices have to meet ground fault/isolation requirements such as 60601-1 ([link](https://www.edn.com/designing-medical-devices-for-isolation-and-safety/)). Particularly galvanic isolation is required on power and data lines to avoid a fault conditions that could electrocute somebody. Do consumer electronics have any such standards that must be met?

I see this is a real issue that kills up to 70 people a year ([link](https://www.consumerreports.org/product-safety/avoid-electrical-hazards-with-your-devices/)) in consumer tech. Based on designs for common devices like cellphones that I have seen there is no particular care taken to ensure that the chassis can't become dangerously energized when charging from something with a 2 prong charger (No Earth GND). Are there cheap methods that provide sufficient protection such as fuses? Galvanic isolation is typically expensive and difficult for large power draws.

Comment: there is a transformer in those phone chargers. There are standards for non medical consumer equipment. Go shopping for ac-dc wall warts on Digikey or Mouser and lo at their datasheets

Comment: I have yet to see a 2-prong charger which is _not_ galvanically isolated...

Comment: @DKNguyen but how does the cellphone guarantee that? You could plug into a USB port with a fault on it just as easy.

Comment: @EasyOhm And what do you think powers the USB port on your computer? The giant power supply (which actually will have a 3-prong plug but that's besides the point here) which has a transformer in it. "What happens if someone plugs it into a USB power source with no transformer?" Well, first of all, that shouldn't have been built to begin with. It'd be like building a car without brakes. You can't idiot-proof everything.